# I have a faulting dll and a fault address - how do I start analysing the error?

Tags: dll, crash, analysis

I have the following two error logs in the Windows Event Viewer of our IIS production server:

> Source: Application Error
>   Category: (100)
>   Event ID: (1000)
>   Description: Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3603, fault address 0x0001da8f.

Seconds later:

> Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
>   Category: None
>   Event ID: 1000
>   Description: Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d6968e, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3603, stamp 4a7cd88e, debug? 0, fault address 0x0001da8f.

What can I do with these error messages?  I see that I have a fault address and a dll name - are there any tools that will show me what is at this address in the dll?  Would this be the correct approach to figuring out what caused the crash?  I've so far not been able to replicate it.

Thanks.

Comment: How has no one answered this yet?

Comment: I have no idea :) I think I earnt the Tumbleweed badge from this question, at least.